# Strange Variable modifications in Morris.js

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I've found something in Morris.js that I can't explain, and hoping someone here might be able to help with.

I've created two JS fiddles which illustrate the problem.

1. The problematic version: (js fiddle included in comments)

   ```
   $("#input").change(function () {
       chart_1.options.goals[0] = $("#input").val();
       chart_1.redraw();
       chart_2.redraw();
   });

   chart_1 = new Morris.Bar({
       element: 'chart_1', 
       barColors: ["black"], 
       goalLineColors: ["blue"], 
       data: [
           {year: "2008", value: 5}, 
           {year: "2009", value: 10}, 
           {year: "2010", value: 15}, 
           {year: "2011", value: 20}, 
           {year: "2012", value: 25}, 
       ], 
       xkey: 'year', 
       ykeys: ['value'], 
       labels: ['value']});

   chart_2 = new Morris.Bar({
       element: 'chart_2', 
       barColors: ["blue"], 
       goalLineColors: ["red"], 
       data: [
           {year: "2008", value: 25}, 
           {year: "2009", value: 20}, 
           {year: "2010", value: 15}, 
           {year: "2011", value: 10}, 
           {year: "2012", value: 5}, 
       ], 
       xkey: 'year', 
       ykeys: ['value'], 
       labels: ['value']});
   ```

As you can see, I'm only modifying chart_1, but chart_2 receives the same change!

2. A workaround/solution: (js fiddle in comment) is to initialize the goals array

   ```
   chart_1 = new Morris.Bar({
       element: 'chart_1',
       barColors: ["black"],
       goals: [],
   ```

Q1: how is the problem even possible? I'm not touching chart_2, but it's being modified (confirmed by examination of the objects in chrome developer tools).

Q2: why does the workaround work?

I'm not sure if it's a bug (reported here - https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/issues/656 - but given Morris.js is no longer being updated, SO seems a better bet for help!) or if I've failed to understand something in JS - either way, looking forward to learning something.

Comment: Problem Replicated in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7dbwkth6/

Comment: Workaround in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v3c5Lg4c/2/

Comment: Sorry for using the comments to paste the fiddle, but SO on my phone wasn't formatting code properly to let me post the JSFiddle links in the main post. as soon as I have access to a proper pc, I'll fix this post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be happening because when morris.js merges the default chart options with your chart options it keeps the reference to the array that is in the default chart options. So when doing this merge several times, it will point to the same array every time.

In your problematic code you can test this by comparing the arrays:

```
console.log(chart_1.options.goals === chart_2.options.goals); // logs true
```

So since they are the same, doing `chart_1.options.goals[0] = $("#input").val();` is the same as doing it for `chart_2`, as they operate on the same goals array.

This is also why your workaround works. You are making sure that each chart has a distinct array. If you do the same comparison as above in your workaround code you'll see that they are not the same.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me. And what I had suspected. Will have to pull apart Morris and confirm.